# Accessing environment variables at design time in SSDT?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, parameter

I'm re-designing some SSIS packages for 2012 and some parameter/variable/configuration issues are not clear to me.

The result that I am trying to achieve is that the user context's temp folder(stored in the %temp% OS environment variable) is available in my package. Specifically, when I open the package in SSDT, it should expand the environment variable to the current path so that it passes validation. I can get this at run time with script task, but it's ugly working around it at design time. In the SSIS catalog, I can apply an environment variable to a parameter, so that aspect is not an issue.

How can I get this to happen when a project is opened?

Comment: Your need is that during *design* time, you want a variable/parameter to point to a location determined by an OS variable and during run time from the SSISDB catalog, it you'll have that parameter configured from an SSIS Environment variable?

Comment: I believe so. The connection manager fields have expressions that include variables. Those variables come from parameters. In the catalog, parameters can be provided from environment variables. In SSDT, they can come from configurations. I am try to learn if external data can be included in configurations and when that inclusion happens.

Comment: Jeff, in order for a commentator to know that you replied you must use @ and his name in your reply, like @billinkc in this case.